# How to use model.reset_states() in Keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, sequence, lstm

I have sequential data and I declared a LSTM model which predicts `y` with `x` in Keras. So if I call `model.predict(x1)` and `model.predict(x2)`, Is it correct to call `model.reset_states` between the two `predict()` explicitly? Does `model.reset_states` clear history of inputs, not weights, right?

```
# data1
x1 = [2,4,2,1,4]
y1 = [1,2,3,2,1]

# dat2
x2 = [5,3,2,4,5]
y2 = [5,3,2,3,2]
```

And in my actual code, I use `model.evaluate()`. In `evaluate()`, is `reset_states` called implicitly for each data sample?

```
model.evaluate(dataX, dataY)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`reset_states` clears only the hidden states of your network. It's worth to mention that depending on if the option `stateful=True` was set in your network - the behaviour of this function might be different. If it's not set - all states are automatically reset after every batch computations in your network (so e.g. after calling `fit`, `predict` and `evaluate` also). If not - you should call `reset_states` every time, when you want to make consecutive model calls independent.

Comment: I got it. If I do not set stateful option (so default=false), I do not need to call reset_states, right? And could you tell me what kind of cases I should use stateful=True?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `stateful=True` is usually used when you want to treat consecutive batches as consequtive inputs. In this case model is treating consequtive batches the same as it were in the same batch.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko How does the model learn when the hidden states are cleared after every batch training? What does `clear` mean here?

Answer (score 4):

If you use explicitly either of:

```
model.reset_states()
```

to reset the states of all layers in the model, or

```
layer.reset_states()
```

to reset the states of a specific stateful RNN layer (also LSTM layer), implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f9b9cf52eb36a5d5e8bbf96fc1f2b6f584ce7867/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L885):

```
def reset_states(self, states=None):
  if not self.stateful:
     raise AttributeError('Layer must be stateful.')
```

### this means your layer(s) must be stateful.

In LSTM you need to:

- explicitly specify the batch size you are using, by passing a `batch_size` argument to the first layer in your model or `batch_input_shape` argument
- set `stateful=True`.
- specify `shuffle=False` when calling `fit()`.

---

The benefits of using stateful models are probable best explained [here](https://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/).